# Snowflake - update in two tables at once

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi i have a process in which a staging table is loaded each day for a main table after doing a merge from a stream and other table (secondary) is loaded not every day, also with a process that using a stream loads a staging table.

In a final stored procedure, all the rows are loaded from the main table but some columns are loaded from the secondary. In this final procedure first I have a Merge in which i insert new rows or update existing ones (after applying some business rules), after that i currently delete all the raws that have been processed from the staging table.

After that i would love to mark in someway on the staging table of the secondary table if any row was already used to update the rows of the main table (in the final table) or not, something like a 0/1 flag, so only the rows that have the value 1 (suppose 1 mean that was used to update the final table) are finally deleted from the staging table of the secondary table..

Any thoughts if this is a good approach or any other idea?? Thanks